# SyntaxError in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, syntax, compiler-errors, syntax-error

I new to react native. I am trying to compile a simple react native app but I received an SyntaxError.

This is the error I received

```
SyntaxError: C:\Users\admin\Desktop\galio-starter-kit\App.js: Unexpected token (8:6)

   6 |   render() {
   7 |     return (
>  8 |       <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
     |       ^
   9 |         <StatusBar hidden={false} />
  10 |         <GalioApp />
  11 |       </View>
```

This is my App.js code

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, StatusBar } from 'react-native';
import GalioApp from './routes';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <StatusBar hidden={false} />
        <GalioApp />
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Anyone know which syntax error I make? I cannot spot it out.

Comment: I don't find any error in this. Try by restarting your packager and clear cache.

Comment: you seem to be missing a semi after the closing bracket for the return function. does it work after adding it?

Comment: The location of the error may be incorrect. Do you want to delete GalioApp?

Comment: @kenmistry previously I tired with semicolon, get the same error also

Comment: @hongdeveloper Trying remove GalioApp ,get the same error also.

Comment: This looks more like babel has not transpiled your code. how did you create the app?

Comment: @illiteratewriter i follow this link https://github.com/galio-org/galio-starter-kit#quick-start

Comment: Could you try `npm start -- --reset-cache` ??

Comment: @hongdeveloper tried npm start --reset-cache,still get same error